# Cannot change Numpy array elements filtered by boolean indexing

Tags: python, numpy

Reproducible code:

```
x = np.array([0.9, 0.9, 1])
y = np.array([0, 0, 1])
y[x<1] = 1 - x[x<1]
print(y)
```

Output

```
array([0, 0, 1])
```

Desired output

```
array([0.1, 0.1, 1])
```

I know `np.where` will get me the desired output. I'm just curious about why boolean indexing doesn't work in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must specify the dtype for y:

```
y = np.array([0, 0, 1], dtype=np.float64)
```

When you did not specify that, it assume integer as dtype. So each modification on this will be converted to original dtype of this array.